# How to add sfcgal to an already postgis enabled database

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a postgres 9.1 database with postgis 2.1, and I recently needed to add sfcgal to it, so i rebuilt postgis 2.1, but I can't find out how to update the postgis extension in postgres without dropping all data. 
Is there a way to do that ?

```
ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;
```

returns a notice saying i'm already at version 2.1.0

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just run the sfcgal.sql file into your existing database. Unfortunately, cgal is not packaged as an extension (actually, for exactly the reason your case demonstrates: you can't have two extensions with the same version and different capabilities).

Comment: May I suggest you clarify your answer by adding the commands `psql -d database_name -a -f /usr/local/Cellar/postgis/2.1.7_1/share/postgis/sfcgal.sql` and `ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;`? Otherwise nice answer ;) I think the other answer will be more relevant in the future.

Answer (score 6):

from the NEWS files in postgis repository, it seems that with postgis 2.2.0, SFCGAL can now be installed as its own extension using 

`CREATE EXTENSION postgis_sfcgal`

so this will be easier in the future ! :)