# Configuring SFCGAL to PostGIS Db

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sfcgal

I was using PostgreSQL with PostGIS and Pgrouting. Recently I needed to install SFCGAL for some extra functions for my PostGIS db. After installing SFCGAL, now I don't know how to update my PostGIS db to bring those SFCGAL functions into my db?

Paths:

`libSFCGAL.so: /usr/local/lib`

`sfcgal-config: /usr/local/bin`

`SFCGAL: /usr/local/include`

Answer (score 4):

Eventually I have figured out how to add SFCGAL functions to a PostGIS db. According to my research, one cannot configure SFCGAL to an existing PostGIS installation.

The best approach for me was to reinstall PostGIS with SFCGAL configuration.

1. Install [SFCGAL](http://oslandia.github.io/SFCGAL/installation.html). You may need to install prerequisites from terminal like `sudo apt-get install cmake libcgal-dev`. If anything is missing, terminal will inform you.
2. Install Postgresql from the terminal like this `sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.3 postgresql-9.3`.
3. Install [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/source) using `postgis-2.1.5dev.tar.gz` package and while configuring the package run the command like this `sudo ./configure --with-sfcgal=/path/to/the/sfcgal-config/file` (mine was /usr/local/bin/sfcgal-config). You may need to specify further paths also like for Proj4, XML2 etc depending upon your system's declared PATH. Terminal will inform you about any missing PATH (but be careful while writing them).
4. Now my `postgis-2.1` folder is in the `/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/contrib` directory (your may be different). Open the folder and copy the content of `sfcgal.sql` file.
5. Finally in your newly created database run the command `create extension postgis` and then the content you copied from `sfcgal.sql` file. Necessary new functions should be included in your db.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 4):

As it is descibed in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/152937/23119) PostGIS 2.2 now comes with a tool for that:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_sfcgal
```

Comment: Should be the best answer by now!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know SFCGAL cannot be added to an existing PostGIS installation, if the installation was compiled without configuring for SFCGAL support. [Here](http://postgis.net/2015/10/25/postgis_sfcgal_extension/) is some more information on that issue. You will have to compile a SFCGAL enabled version, how to do that for the software versions listed below is described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/188649).

```
Unbuntu Trusty Tar 14.04 LTS
GEOS 3.5.0
PostgreSQL 9.5
SFCGAL 1.3.0
CGAL 4.7.2
```